# webpack error in Cannot find module 'less'

Tags: less, webpack

I'm trying to use less loader in webpack and the issues is - I've installed less loader locally, but when I try to compile everything using webpack command in bask, it prints out: "ERROR in Cannot find module 'less'". In my entry point I require some less file like

```
require("./less_components/style.less");
```

Here is my webpack.config file

```
module.exports = {

entry: "./entry.js",

output: {

    path: "./build",

    filename: "./bundle.js"

},

module: {

    loaders: [

        {test: /\.js$/, exlude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},

        {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less"}

    ]
}
}
```

What's the matter and how I should fix it?

Comment: Do you have `less-loader` in your node_modules?

Comment: Yes, I do, before posting this I thought it was the issue

Comment: ERROR in Cannot find module 'less'
 @ ./less_components/style.less 4:14-167

it's the output I get. The less_components thing is the path to where my style file is located

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed the `less-loader` into your node_modules. Installing it would fix this.

```
npm install less-loader --save-dev
```

Edit: Also you will get this error when you haven't installed the `css-loader` and `style-loader` that you are chaining `less-loader` to.

Anyone who comes across this can plus on the issue I submitted for the bad message. ["Error in Cannot find module 'less'" when missing loaders chained after less. Revise error message](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/issues/89).

Comment: I've it in my loaders

Comment: Can you wipe your node modules and try installing again?

Comment: Also try changing loader name to `less-loader` instead of `less`. That will help confirm its the loader it can't find because the error message will show `less-loader` instead.

Comment: I changed it to the less-loader, but the message I'm getting is still the same, with "less module", not "less-loader"

Comment: Can you check and make sure you also have the css-loader and style-loaders installed? https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/issues/45

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue was - I didn't have the css-loader and also less, cuz without either of them, the console kept sending the error

Comment: I had the exact same error and tried `npm install less-loader style-loader css-loader --save-dev`. However, that didn't do it, but once I installed the module `less`, i.e. without the `-loader` suffix, the error went away!

Comment: Should be noted: If you are using the local web server provided by webpack for testing, the server may need to be restarted to completely resolve newly installed modules and their paths.

Answer (score 73):

This error happens because npm@3 does not resolve peerDependencies any more.

`npm install less less-loader` is the way to go.

Comment: I would add --save-dev as less is usually only required for development

Comment: Thank you guys this solution helps.

Comment: who decided to not install required dependencies?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue.
ERROR in Cannot find module 'less'

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY file-loader@*
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY less@^2.3.1
├── webpack@1.13.2 
└── webpack-dev-server@1.16.2 
npm WARN EPEERINVALID less-loader@2.2.3 requires a peer of less@^2.3.1 
but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID url-loader@0.5.7 requires a peer of file-loader@* 
but none was installed.
```

I tried as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev less
npm install --save-dev file-loader
```

Then it solved the issues.

Comment: Same here, previous answer didn't work but a simple `npm i less` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with a .Net Core project. I resolved this by adding less to my package.json file as well as less-loader.

```
"less-loader": "2.2.3",
"less": "2.7.2"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I already had `less-loader, style-loader and css-loader` still it was giving same error. When I installed less then it fixed. So make sure you install less also. 
`npm install less --save-dev` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

the error message described the problem well: missing 'less' module.

`npm install less --save-dev` will solve it.

Most of the time you should have all of less/less-loader/css-loader/style-loader.

`npm install style-loader css-loader less-loader less --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

@Zhorian yours works awesome, I cannot vote cuz of the low level and neither add comment on your answer! after doing npm install less --save-dev, it works, for the error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'less'
```

and when you try to install:

```
npm install less-loader style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

It will gave you:

```
├── css-loader@0.26.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY less@^2.3.1
├── less-loader@2.2.3
└── style-loader@0.13.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error also when I have installed less and less-loader both.
then I try uninstall them and install them again but not make sense.
[image]

Lastly, I find delete the last dist(already exit) can make 'npm run build' right.
So, you can try delete the 'dist' dir if it already exits.