# How do I resolve peer dependency error: The package react@15.3.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I am getting this error when I run npm install. This seems because I am unable to satisfy some peer dependency but I am unsure which peer dependency I need to fix.

```
λ npm install

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.3.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer belle@2.0.7 wants react@>=0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer material-ui@0.15.4 wants react@^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-infinite@0.9.2 wants react@^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-input-field@1.2.4 wants react@>=0.12.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@0.13.6 wants react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-tap-event-plugin@0.2.2 wants react@^0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-toolbox@1.2.1 wants react@~0.14 || ~15.3.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.3.2 wants react@^15.3.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.3.2 wants react@^15.3.2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Daljeet\Documents\hive\client\npm-debug.log
```

I have also attached a copy of the package.json

```
dependencies: 

  "dependencies": {
    "belle": "^2.0.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "compression": "^1.0.11",
    "config": "^1.21.0",
    "config-js": "^1.1.9",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.4.1",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "dotenv": "^0.4.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "express-jwt": "^0.3.1",
    "flux": "^2.0.1",
    "i": "^0.3.5",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^1.1.0",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.0.0",
    "log4js": "^0.6.38",
    "material-ui": "~0.15.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.3.4",
    "morgan": "^1.2.3",
    "normalize.css": "^4.2.0",
    "pg": "^4.5.5",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-infinite": "^0.9.2",
    "react-input-field": "^1.2.4",
    "react-mixin": "^1.1.0",
    "react-router": "^0.13.2",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "~0.2.2",
    "react-toolbox": "^1.2.1",
    "react-virtual-list": "^1.8.0",
    "reqwest": "2.0.5",
    "when": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^6.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.1.6",
    "browserify": "^8.0.3",
    "clean-css": "^3.1.9",
    "eslint": "^0.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.5.0",
    "rework": "^1.0.1",
    "rework-npm": "^1.0.0",
    "rework-npm-cli": "^0.1.1",
    "serve": "^1.4.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.4.15",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having this same problem. In a more condensed form: I'm being told v15.3.2 does not satisfy peer dependency ^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 —— which is just wrong, it does satisfy that semver range.

Comment: Could you cut all the npm warnings from your first code block? Those are kind of irrelevant: the errors are the issue.

Comment: i thought the warnings may provide insight into dealing with the errors.

Comment: it worked when i updated npm `"npm install npm -g"` and then downgraded react to; `"react": "15.3.0"`, cleared cache: `npm cache clear`, removed node_modules, `rm -rf node_modules`, and reinstalled, `npm install`.

Comment: just by updating npm `npm install npm -g` can solve the problem.

Comment: `npm i <your_package> --force` worked for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

it worked when I:

---

1. updated npm `"npm install npm -g"`
2. downgraded react to; `"react": "15.3.0"`
3. cleared cache: `npm cache clear`
4. removed node_modules, `rm -rf node_modules`,
5. reinstalled node_modules, `npm install`.

Comment: What does `npm install npm -g` actually do? Installs npm package from npm?

Comment: @ŁukaszJagodziński it is to upgrade npm to latest version. This is npm magic, manage it by itself.

Answer (score 38):

For me `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` worked. Please read about this flag before using it.

`--legacy-peer-deps`: ignore all peerDependencies when installing (in the style of npm version 4 through version 6).

Comment: Would be great if you could explain it in your answer as well :)

Answer (score 8):

Just update node package manager (npm) to the latest version.

```
npm install npm -g
```

Comment: This worked for by peer dependencies warnings but any explanation on why it worked?

Comment: Probably because in the earlier version of npm, they did not resolve peer dependencies.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781031/webpack-error-in-cannot-find-module-less

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I used following things:

1. Update the react version: "react": ^16.2.0" in package.json file
2. Delete the node modules by rm -rf node_modules
3. Run npm install
4. npm update

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to resolve this when installing the node module

**`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`**

if above doesn't work for you then you can tey **`npm install --force`**

**`--legacy-peer-deps:`** ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues until I

```
removed node_modules, rm -rf node_modules,
Made changes to package.json,
cleared cache: npm cache clear --force,
reinstalled node_modules, npm install.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).