# Unable to decode jwt with jwt-decode

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to decode my token with jwt-decode but I can't. It gives me the following error. Does anyone know why?

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: jwt_decode_1.default is
>   not a function TypeError: jwt_decode_1.default is not a function
>       at RoleGuardService.canActivate (role-guard.service.ts?d7c4:19)

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // this will be passed from the route config
        // on the data property
        const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        // decode the token to get its payload
        const tokenPayload = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log(tokenPayload);
        if (
            !this.auth.isAuthenticated() ||
            tokenPayload.role !== expectedRole
        ) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you should import it like this:

```
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't works in Angular 10. When the jwt_decode is called, I receive a runtime error that jwt_decode__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ is not a function.

Comment: Same here, but I overlooked the new import style for jwt_decode 3.
Importing as proposed below by @sorin-veștemean fixed the problem here.

Comment: Warning: When upgrading from version 2 to 3, there's a potentially breaking change

If you've previously imported the library as import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode', you'll have to change your import to import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

Answer (score 8):

According to [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) + internet search, the correct way is:

**1. Install the package + types**

`npm install --save jwt-decode`

`npm install --save @types/jwt-decode`

2. When you import the jwt_decode, you should surpass a rule from tslint, your code will look exactly like this (with commented line above)

> ```
>  // @ts-ignore  
> import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
> ```

Otherwise you will get an error like this
[image]

You can add also the rule for that on tsconfig.json , but is 1 time exception :)

Comment: This works but why is not possibile to use the notation `import { JwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode'`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but after many attempts I did manage to solve this problem by using another method:

```
private decode(token: string) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split(".")[1]));
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn("Error decoding token");
    }
}
```

function atob() [references](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)

Answer (score 1):

**jwt_decode** has always been a CommonJS module which generally are imported as `const jwt_decode = require('jwt-decode');`, it's what Node.js uses.

The way to import CommonJS libraries with a JS `import` statement is `import * as library-name from 'library-name;`.

Modern frameworks like Angular 10 throw a warning when using packages with the CommonJS format, because they generally speaking can't be tree-shaked.

Version 3 (now in beta) of this library includes a more modern ESM build, which is what JS import statements are meant for, so importing the modern ESM package can be done the regular way using `import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';`. This is a breaking change, that's why I've created a new major version `3`.

We still have a CommonJS build, but by default most modern build systems for the web (not node) will use the ESM build.

if you checkout the `package.json` file when installing the lib, you'll notice both builds in there.

```
{
    ...
    "main": "build/jwt-decode.cjs.js",
    "module": "build/jwt-decode.esm.js",
    ...
}
```

[references](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/97)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the problem for you:

```
import base64 from 'react-native-base64'; export const decode = (token) => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(base64.decode(token.split(".")[1]));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error decoding token:", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

npm install --save jwt-decode

npm install --save @types/jwt-decode
```

This solves mine problem

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65770472/5517312)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in react-native CLI.

[Package: npm i base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64)

```
import {decode} from 'base-64';
global.atob = decode;

const decodeToken = (token: string) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(decode(token.split('.')[1]));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    return null;
  }
};

const decodedResult = await decodeToken(token as string); // Your token
```