# Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular9

When trying to install the npm packages using `npm i` command, I am getting the following exception:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling the Node.js package and setting the proxy to off using:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
```

The issue is still there. What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

When I run the following command:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

The following error is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Show your package.json - it looks like you've upgraded @angular/core, but did not upgrade  @angular/http?

Comment: my @angular/core version is 9.1.4, so shall i update @angular/http?

Comment: Can you try to delete package-lock.json and node_modules and try to run npm update? Let me know if it work.

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? If it is 7.0.4 you should update, because it has a bug: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2000

Comment: npm version 7.0.5

Comment: The package-lock.json is not available. Yes, I have tried deleting node_modules  with no luck.

Comment: For vue 2 use:
`npm install -S vue-router@3`

Error happens quz `npm i vue-router` defaults to downloading the latest version which is not compatible with vue 2

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64573177/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 840, accepted):

This is not related to an HTTP proxy.

You have **dependency conflict** (*incorrect* and potentially *broken* dependency) as it says, so try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`. If it doesn't take effect, the **temporary solution** is *using prior versions of the Node.js* (downgrading the Node.js version) as it causes this kind of errors to happen sometimes.

**Update based on the OP's update**:

As you see, it fires the following error:

> No matching version found for @angular/http@^9.1.4.

Take a look at [`angular/http` page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http). **Note** that the latest version for that deprecated package is `7.2.16` while *you request an upper version (e.g., `^9.1.4`)*! So, try to check the project dependencies and follow the raised errors in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @Pearl please show the output result of `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` commands

Comment: Thanks  `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` works for me

Comment: will that flag install only peer deps?

Comment: @Aashiqahmed It tells NPM to *ignore* peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway

Comment: ,react folder in project >  Open in Integrated Terminal

I had this following error
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Below command worked.  thanks
 npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Thanks, downgrade node version from 15 to 14 worked for me.

Comment: As it turns out, some packages manage to break peer dependencies on all their own, they don't even need to depend on the project being worked on to break. Happens a lot with packages made for legacy versions of Angular and React.

Comment: always update version by version. for example if you are in 10, and now angular latest version is 12 means, you should update 11 and then to 12. not directly 10 to 12. it avoids more issues.

Comment: `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` will definitely work on local, but what happens when we send this for build on the environment, wouldn't it break there?

Comment: Use `npm ci --legacy-peer-deps` if you have the package-lock.json file.

Answer (score 369):

Try the below command-

`--legacy-peer-deps` This option is used when it encounter compatibility issues with peer dependencies in the project. Peer dependencies are a way for a package to specify that it relies on another package but doesn't want to include it as a direct dependency. This allows multiple packages to depend on a common package without having multiple copies of it in your project.

The `--legacy-peer-deps` option tells the package manager (npm or Yarn) to use an older, more lenient approach when resolving and installing packages with peer dependency conflicts. It can be useful if you're working with older packages that haven't updated their peer dependency definitions to align with newer package manager behavior.

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: If using npm 5 or greater no need --save flag as it automatically saves dependencies

Comment: It half-installs Angular 7, and half-installs angular 9. If you do this, it might actually work, but may god have mercy on you, because you're DEFINITELY running some libraries that are incompatible with your current version of Angular.

Answer (score 345):

First to understand the problem. Here is what I have as error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project-admin@11.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"11.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"3.0.0-beta.0" from the root project
```

First you should start to read the problem from the bottom to the top. Here @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0 requires *angular* *common* 9.1.0 or 10.0.0. And the top message says that the *angular* *common* found is actually 11.0.3.

*(If you want to understand dependencies little bit better, here is very simple site: [How npm3 Works](https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html))*

```
dependencies — these are the essential dependencies that you rely on and call in your project’s code
devDependencies — these are your development dependencies, for example, a prettier library for formatting code
peerDependencies — if you set a peer dependency in your package.json, you are telling the person who installs your package that they need that dependency with the specified version
optionalDependencies — these dependencies are optional and failing to install them will not break the installation process
bundledDependencies — it’s an array of packages that will come bundled with your package. This is useful when some 3rd party library is not on NPM, or you want to include some of your projects as modules
```

So what should be the solution then? The problem is about peer dependencies. The solution is to downgrade *angular* *common* ***or*** the solution is to use legacy dependencies logic for installing packages using *--legacy-peer-deps*. So *--legacy-peer-deps* does not try to install the peerDependencies automatically. Is this going to work for you? Probably, yes. But you should add specific instructions how to do that, or to make the use of *--legacy-peer-deps* automatic for future installation of the project packages with this code from one of the previous answers:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

In my case I installed the package and I tried to run `ng serve`, but because *--legacy-peer-deps* was used, there were dependency packages which were not installed. I had to install those manually (because I did not set the configuration from the code above). At the end installing about five packages manually, all with *--legacy-peer-deps*, I ended to a package that could not be installed and I did not try to continue, because my project was throwing warnings like crazy and there were a lot of packages for audit too. So my decision was not to use this package and to find an alternative.

Other solutions that I read about along the way:

- downgrade Node.js to v14. This will downgrade npm. It might not be v14, but this was the version that was most widely downgraded to.
- Some people use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) to force package installation - personally I don't understand how this works, because I haven't used Yarn.
- downgrading Angular and the global Angular CLI version to version that will satisfy the requirement. In my case it is *angular/common*, and in the question it's *angular/core*, but both require downgrading the whole angular right (I am not sure about this here).
- the package you install might have a higher version that doesn't require downgrading Angular. You might try to use the https://updatepackagejson.com/ to upgrade your packages to the latest, but this is in case your project is quite new.

Comment: That's the best answer because it is the only answer which explained the error log from OP instead of stupidly applying force or legacy-peer-deps option.
Better to stick to npm 6 than pushing npm 7 and force/legacy-peer-deps on it to avoid fixing your dependencies issues

Comment: By far the best answer, others just fix the issue, but not caring about the underlying problem nor give insightful suggestions on why the issue is occurring.

Comment: I'm new to npm but I believe using npm install --force is better, because it only ignores peer-dependencies when necessary, while --legacy-peer-deps adopts the npm v6 approach and ignores peer-dependencies completely. See @Hongbo Miao's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps#answer-66608842

Comment: `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` is the magic, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much.  I understood the concept of dependencies and all that, but you explained what the error message was saying.  I kept trying to read from top to bottom, so I was drawing completely the wrong conclusions.  I wish the error were more user friendly, but your explanation made it possible to understand what the error message is saying.

Comment: if you want to check where is coming from the package, in case this is installed by another package, you can use: npm ls --depth 1

Comment: from my understanding `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` will apply to all projects as it is a global config. This might not be desirable.

Answer (score 135):

In addition to using the `--legacy-peer-deps` command line option, this can also be set more permanently as a configuration option:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Comment: The best option if `npm install` is run indirectly, e.g. by a script.

Comment: what does this do

Comment: @Arefe, Aashiq explained in another, similar answer, that this command (legacy-peer-deps) "tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway"

Comment: npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

This command is working for me, Thanks

Answer (score 74):

When using `npm` 7, this comes up a lot because peer dependencies issues are treated as errors in version 7 whereas they were generally only warnings in version 6. Usually using `--legacy-peer-deps` makes it work with `npm` 7.

When that doesn't work, an option is to downgrade to `npm` 6. Downgrading Node.js is not necessary (but not harmful either). The relevant dependency management code is in `npm`. Downgrading Node.js will often work coincidentally because doing so will often downgrade `npm` as well.

Another option that is less disruptive than downgrading `npm` is using `npx` to use the previous version of `npm` for just the install command: `npx -p npm@6 npm install`

And when all else fails, it's often worth a shot to remove the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json`, and then run `npm install` again. That regenerates `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Comment: What is the best way to permanently downgrade to npm 6?

Comment: @alentejo by removing the npm folder in theC:\Users\{your name}\AppData\Roaming , npm cache clear --force and then npm install -g npm@<version>

Answer (score 68):

First, execute this in your terminal.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Second, clear the cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And finally, execute your command.

Comment: Does clearing cache help here? Do we really need Step 2?

Comment: Please add explanation.

Answer (score 61):

This happens for some packages after updating to npm 7.

Parameter `--legacy-peer-deps` can help:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Described here [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Causes npm to completely ignore peerDependencies when building a
> package tree, as in npm versions 3 through 6.
>
> If a package cannot be installed because of overly strict
> peerDependencies that collide, it provides a way to move forward
> resolving the situation.
> ...

You can set this option to `true` by default (not recommended by npm):

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Or just wait until these packages get up to date.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is related to a dependency conflict or broken dependency. You can proceed by accepting the incorrection of dependency by forcing an install.

**Solution:** Using command with `--force`.

Your command will be like `npm install --force @your-npm-package`.

**Note:** You can use `yarn` to install a dependency if it's available in to install with the yarn package manager.

Answer (score 14):

`NPM` can be used to install and manage versions of dependencies in your projects.

I had it the same issue on React versions in relation with the npm version:

> npm error found types/react@16.14.20

So it might be package-versions that need to be installed based on your *package.json* file.

It gives errors in the npm 7 version and cannot install Node.js modules.

If you will **downgrade** npm version to 6, those problems will become warnings and the problem will be resolved.

- Try to prove this command: **npm install -g npm@6**
- Check if version is already installed: ***npm --version***
- Remove and install node_modules package:

  a) Remove **rm -rf node_modules**

  b) Install: ***npm i***

Answer (score 13):

*Disclaimer: This assumes you're on npm v7+*

**Note:** If you follow the instructions of sibling commenters, [it will create a user-scoped config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#location) that won't sync consistently across teammates / machines / buildbots.

#### Project-based legacy peer dependencies

You will probably want [`legacy-peer-deps`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps) **tied to your project** so it proliferates across machines / developers, and doesn't contaminate your other projects.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true --location project
```

This will create a local file at `.npmrc` which you can commit to your repository:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

Then afterwards, you can just run:

```
npm install
```

Then commit the updated lockfile.

Remember, [location, location, location](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#location):

- **per-project configuration** (`/path/to/my/project/.npmrc`, [see more](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#location:%7E:text=per%2Dproject%20configuration)):

  ```
  npm config set legacy-peer-deps true --location project
  ```
- **per-user configuration** (defaults to `$HOME/.npmrc`, [see more](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#location:%7E:text=per%2Duser%20configuration%20file))

  ```
  npm config set legacy-peer-deps true --location user
  ```

  or, as the default location is user anyway:

  ```
  npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
  ```
- **global configuration** (defalts to `$PREFIX/etc/npmrc`, [see more](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#location:%7E:text=global%20configuration%20file))

  ```
  npm config set legacy-peer-deps true --location global
  ```

  or, as `--global` infers `--location global`

  ```
  npm config set legacy-peer-deps true --global
  ```

### For some projects, fixing dependencies may be non-trivial

In my case, a critical dependency we have a legacy version of wants to pull in webpack v3 (!) - but that's a build dependency of that project's.

The best solution on a short term basis is to use `legacy-peer-deps` as a hold over.

If you are in a pinch, you could also consider forking the dependency and adjusting its peer dependencies accordingly - then point your project to the fork.

Answer (score 11):

Try removing the `node modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run command `npm install`
or
Try `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 11):

First I tried

```
npm install
```

It gave me error `unable to resolve dependency tree` and based on the help information from this command,

```
Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried this command:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

Try two options to resolve this issue:

- Option 1: Delete folder [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and file *package_lock.json* after running:
  `npm cache clean --force after npm i --force`
- Option 2: run `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 9):

You can install the packages using two ways it is showing this error:

```
ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

1. Install the package using `npm install` and having `--legacy-peer-deps`

   ```
   npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
   ```
2. This is a combination of two commands

   a. Set legacy-peer-deps true in `npm config`

   ```
   npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
   ```

   b. Now install packages using `npm install`

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Answer (score 8):

The fastest solution: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

**Explanation:**

> In npm versions 3 through 6, peerDependencies were not automatically installed, and would raise a warning if an invalid version of the peer dependency was found in the tree. As of npm v7, peerDependencies are **installed by default**.
>
> [npm docs: peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies)

Your dependency contains some peerDependencies that conflict with the root project's dependency.

As it described in the `npm ERR` log.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that `gf-kautomata-pipeline-ui` is using Angular 9, while `@angular/http` *requires* Angular 7. (`@angular/http` was deprecated and eventually removed, and all its functionality was moved into `@angular/common` instead.)

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http

If you're running Angular 9, then

1. delete `@angular/http` from your `package.json` (You don't need it in Angular 9)
2. Make sure you have `@angular/common` in your `package.json`.
3. Run `npm i`.

If you're running Angular 7, then open up your package.json and check to make sure all of your Angular packages are no higher than ^7.0.0. You may also need remove gf-kautomata-pipeline-ui, or contact the author of gf-kautomata-pipeline-ui and find out if the library is compatible with Angular 7.

Comment: @Pearl I see in the comments you wrote that your @angular/core is Angular 9, not Angular 7. Are you half-way through an upgrade from 7 to 9?

Comment: This is definitely the most accurate answer

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I started getting the error (below) after upgrading `npm` from version 6 to 7.

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree
>
> ...
>
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

In my case compiling with either `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` flags resulted in a useless bundle.

So I tried deleting the `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and bundle using `yarn install`. This generated a *yarn.lock* file and created package-lock.json that worked fine in subsequent npm runs.

P.S.: I am using the temporary workaround until `npm` 7 works fine with my project: after that, I will delete *yarn.lock*, *package-lock.json* and folder *node_modules*, and recompile with `npm`

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
yarn install
# Generates a yarn.lock file and a new package-lock.json

# Continue with npm
npm start
```

Answer (score 2):

I just update my Node.js and it works for me:

```
node -v
```

Output:

```
V xxxx
```

And:

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

(Use this command to install the stable node release.)

```
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file in your root directory then remove those:

   ```
   rm -r node_modules
   rm package-lock.json
   ```
2. Then run commands:

   ```
   npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
   npm audit fix --force
   ```
3. Create `.env` file in the root directory and paste below code:

   ```
   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
   ```
4. Now, start your project:

   ```
   npm start
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue many times. At last I found a solution:

```
npm install react-native-paper  --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on GitHub actions while pushing my updated package and package-lock JSON file.

The issue was in our inconsistency in-house NPM packages.
I had to add

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

in our *.npmrc* file to override the dependency.

So I feel sometimes it's better to use *legacy-peer-deps* to override unwanted dependencies in your project packages.

Answer (score 2):

npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps word for me with Angular 13.

Comment: I don't  have Word in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Here, most of the answers indicate two solutions:

```
npm i --force
```

and

```
npm i -legacy-peer-deps
```

Surely they are the quick solution. Let's understand what they do actually.

The `npm i --force` command is used with Node Package Manager (npm) to install packages forcefully. When you run this command, npm will install the specified packages, even if they are incompatible with the current version of your project or if there are potential conflicts with other dependencies.

When you use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`, npm will use the older, more flexible algorithm for resolving peer dependencies, which is similar to how peer dependencies were resolved in npm versions 4 and earlier. This can be helpful in situations where packages haven't been updated to declare compatibility with the stricter peer dependency rules introduced in npm 5. Also, this problem still exists in your project. Whenever you try to install any other project, you have to extend the installation the `--force` or `-legacy-peer-deps`

Both options are not recommended if there is any other unbreakable solution.

I also used this in most of my projects. But recently, I tried a different way. Let me explain what I did.

1. delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. listed all the packages from `package.json` to a notepad.
4. Then removed the dependencies from `package.json`
5. Later, install all the dependencies manually, like `npm i package1 package2`
6. After that, I had to fix some version upgrade issues, but finally I got rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I was having the issue

> ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

in an Angular 13 project that used some packages from a private npm feed in [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server).

To access this repository, I created an .npmrc file. Because of this, the npm install command would search all packages in my private repository and not in npm feed any more. The **unable to resolve the dependency tree** error happened because the npm install command could not find many of the packages that were hosted in the npm feed and not my private feed.

I found [this amazing answer on how to scope packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38499150/14132160).

Based on this, I made some changes:

1. In my library **Package.json**, update the name to have a scope name @mylib

   ```
   "name": "@myLib/command-queue",
   ```
2. Build and publish this package to my private feed
3. In my client app (the one that uses this package), update the **.npmrc** file to use my private feed for packages in this scope only

   ```
   @myLib:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...
   always-auth=true
   ```

Now, whenever I run the command **npm install**, if the package has the scope @myLib, it will look for it in my private feed, and use the npm feed for all other cases (i.e., @angular/...)

This is an example of my client app **Package.json** file:

```
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",        <-- this comes from npm
    "@myLib/jcg-command-queue": "^2.2.0", <-- This comes from my private feed
```

Also, with this change, there isn't any need to add **--legacy-peer-deps** to the npm install command any more.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, resulting in the error below:

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
>
> ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm
>
> ERR!
> npm 
> ERR! While resolving: @angular/material-moment-adapter@12.1.4 npm
>
> ERR! Found: @angular/material@12.0.6 npm 
> ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/material npm 
> ERR!   @angular/material@"~12.0.4"
> from the root project
>
> ...

We use `npm ci` for **c**lean **i**nstall in [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops).

The issue was very often that [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) and *package-lock.json* were not in sync anymore.

The solution to it was to execute `npm install` local and push the new `package-lock.json`.

As an additional hint, we added a new task in the pipeline for additional information if the job fails.

```
- task: Npm@1
   displayName: npm install
   inputs:
     command: custom
     customCommand: ci
     customRegistry: useNpmrc

 # ##vso[task.logissue type=error] writes the text to the summary page (error-log).
 - bash: echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error] If 'npm install' fails with 'ERESOLVE could not resolve', 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (needed for 'npm ci') may be out of sync. Run 'npm install' locally and push the new package-lock.json."
   condition: failed() # Only execute on fail
   displayName: npm install failed hint
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this command and it worked for me on Macbook pro 2016.

```
> npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Then

```
> npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Resetting `package-lock.json` works good for me all the time:

```
git checkout -- package-lock.json
```

*Details:*
Been experiencing this a lot when updating all packages of the legacy project - I highly don't recommend using `npm audit fix` nor `npm i --force`. Deleting the `package-lock.json` didn't work for me all the time as well. Rollback to the working version of `package.json + package-lock.json` and add packages turned out to be the safest and fastest variant for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having trouble with a **@babel/core** dependency, but I didn't want to use `--force`, because I was not sure about the consequences, so I went to https://www.npmjs.com/, looked for the package and replaced my old version with the newest one. That did the work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I did have similar behavior, when I tried either `npm upgrade` my current Angular 11.x based boilerplate from previous `ng new` or create new `ng new abc` based on Angular 12.x. I simply forgot to upgrade Angular CLI. So this `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` solved my errors during `ng new abc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of Node.js version. Some latest versions of Node.js could show errors like these.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

I use NVM to manage Node.js versions on the system and use Node.js 12 to get past this error.

Command to change version:

```
nvm use 12
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, npm 8.19.3, all I had to do was to first remove the package which caused the problem (in my case, it was *@angular/material*) and then update my Angular version (with `ng update @angular/cli`), then install my package and everything went fine.

The problem was, I had Angular version at 15.something, while `npm install @angular/material` was trying to install 16.something of itself and that caused dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node_modules folder helped me, after which I ran the command `npm i --force`

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing NPM, you can leverage the new overrides feature. By specifying the desired version of a dependency in the overrides section of your package.json, you can enforce its usage.

Check the official documentation for more details: [NPM Overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)

Example:

```
"overrides": {
  "next": "^14.1.1-canary.59"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading Node.js is the process of installing a previous version of the Node.js software on your system. Downgrading to version 14 can be useful if you have compatibility issues with a newer version of Node.js, or if you want to use a version of Node.js that you are already familiar with. The steps to downgrade Node.js to version 14 are as follows:

1. Source your bash profile: Before you can downgrade Node.js, you need to make sure that you have the necessary environment variables set up. The first step is to source your bash profile using the following command:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

2. Use nvm to switch to version 14: The next step is to use the Node Version Manager (nvm) to switch to version 14 of Node.js. You can do this by using the following command:

`nvm use v14.16.1`

Note that the version number v14.16.1 is just an example. You can use any other version number of Node.js v14 that you have installed on your system.

3. Install npm: Finally, you need to install the Node Package Manager (npm) so that you can manage packages and dependencies in your Node.js project. You can do this by using the following command:

`npm install`

After running these commands, you should have Node.js v14 installed on your system, and you can start using it to build your applications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) has a feature for solving this. If you can, try to use it for installing the package.

Comment: Can you please state which feature?