# I am trying to install new component using npm. But it gives error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm-install

I was trying to add `$ npm install react-native-touchable-bounce --save` but it was giving an error the same as the following.
then I deleted all `node_modules` still getting this error.
`npm install` gives the following error.

```
PS I:\Code\singal res\code\singalRes> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined      
npm ERR! Found: react-native-svg@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   react-native-svg@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-svg@"^9.13.6" from @ui-kitten/components@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ui-kitten/components
npm ERR!   @ui-kitten/components@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\softb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\softb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-14T03_13_39_660Z-debug.log
```

Comment: $npm install  --force ,might help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for me adding the `--force` flag fixed the issue

`npm i --force`

Answer (score 5):

maybe it's because of the lib version mismatch, you can delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`,
then try `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

***Temporary Solution***

This issue can be fixed by running `npm i your-dependency --force` .

> This issue occurs because ***npm can't automatically fix*** the dependencies
> mismatch.

***Cause***

If you want to know why this happen go [***here***.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139353/15142650)

***Permanent Solution***

If you never heard about [yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn), its new package manager came after npm. it is very similar to npm and it has many benefits. one of them is it can automatically fix this issue.

[How to install yarn.](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable)

By the way, there are many new emerging package managers too [pnpm](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable) and others.