# npm install ngx-image-zoom dependency error - best way to resolve - could not resolve dependency error

Tags: angular, npm

In a previous version of an angular project (10) I was using ngx-image-zoom component. I remember having some difficulty with installing due to dependencies with angular 10 but somehow I resolved it. Now I have a new project with angular 11 and I get the following errors
[screen shot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO9BZ.jpg)
and I don't know what the proper way to resolve it. Could anyone advise? It's obvious the ngx image zoom component has some dependency on angular 9 but what is the best way to tackle this. Does it need angular 9 or should it work with 11?

I tried following other answers to this problem at this link
[similar question and possible answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)
but none worked. I'd like to understand why it's happening so I can resolve on my own again if it was ever to arise again

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no working npm package for Angular image zoom except [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier).
I have tried almost all available packages, but couldn't find better then this.

It is fully functional with many customisation options.

This image zoom similar to Amazon or W3school will work for you.