# npm install fails (unable to resolve dependency tree)

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

Trying to reduce any changing variables and using a fresh pull of my code. They are no `node-module` packages or `package-lock.json`. I run `npm install` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-screens@2.15.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-screens
npm ERR!   react-native-screens@"~2.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-screens@"^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha" from react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!   react-navigation-drawer@"^1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/myname/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2021-05-22T01_16_02_351Z-debug.log
```

If I do an install via `--force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` I get a bunch of files mark as outdated and when I run `npm update` I get the same error. I have tried clearning the cache of my npm as well with no luck `npm cache clean`. I don't know why this is happening as there is no node-module folder or anything installed for it to give error under my `node_modules/react-native-screens`...they are no node_modules folder yet. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

**Edit:**
I ran `npm update -g` , then `npm audit fix` and then I got an error:

```
code ERESOLVE
ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

While resolving: Sculp latest app@undefined
Found: react-native-screens@2.15.2
node_modules/react-native-screens
react-native-screens@“~2.15.0” from the root project
```

so I ran `expo install react-native-screens` and saw that it couldn't find expo...checked my folder and my `node_module` folder is missing. Like if it never was there or gotten installed.

**edit:**
I have tried all the methods listed below and it gives random errors that I can not fix it `undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘_core.ThemeColors.light’)` and I have googled this and one of the main solutions is delete npm and package-lock.json and reinstall but that brings me back to where I started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works for me:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: everything installs but then it throws one error after another and the last error that I can't fix is `undefined is not an object (evaluating
‘_core.ThemeColors.light’)`

Comment: worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Note: this will set this flag permanently

For one time:

npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy your src folder and package.json file and initialize another react-native (new) and replace the source the src folder and package.json file and reenter npm install.

Comment: can you show your folder structure before and after reinstalling all the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --force in the command line, but you will problably have to deal with a broken react-native dependency later. Anyway, there are other ways of dealing with this broken dependency.

Answer (score -3):

Try it in the following:

```
npm add react-native
expo install (your needed module)
```