# Unable to resolve dependency tree for angular-ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

Node version: v16.3.0 
ng version: 12.1.0

**Working on angular-ionic 5 project**

1. While performing **npm install** getting below error[image]

2.Tried performing **npm install --force** getting below error
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to pace the upgrades of node versions with the angular versions... going directly to node v16 will cause a lot of dependency issues.

Looking at your error, it seems you are starting at angular version 5.x which was alive from 2017 to 2018, the matching nodejs version at that point was 9.x and 10.x.

I would suggest you install node v10, to do the first angular upgrades up to the moment where it starts to be harder to progress.

then you install node v12 and do some more angular upgrades; and keep increasing the node angular versions on a slower pace until you have then all upgraded to the latest.