# angular has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^>=10.0.0 <14.0.0", would install "13.2.3")

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library, angular13

I do become the following error while trying to update angular from v12 to v13 ?

`Package "@an/example" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^>=10.0.0 <14.0.0", would install "13.2.3").`

@an/example just required the following as peerDependencies

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=10.0.0 <14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^>=10.0.0 <14.0.0"
  },
```

And if I want to update to 13.2.3, then it shouldn't be a problem... Or does it?

*I know I could `--force` my way out*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@babel/types build errors on ng build command in Angular 8.2.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740409/babel-types-build-errors-on-ng-build-command-in-angular-8-2-14)

Comment: or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70740697/4604645)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this may be the same error or how it may help me solve the problem. Do you think I should update my node or npm version ? I'm actually using node v14.18.1 and npm 7.24.2, but as the answer says, npm 7 is the one to use

Comment: The problem is your npm version, you probably upgraded it recently, right?

Comment: No, not for several month (maybe 6). This does come since I've upgrade to angular v13