# cannot uninstall broken angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have a broken copy of the angular cli that I am unable to uninstall.

Simply calling `npm uninstall @angular/cli -g` does not work, because `ng version` will still show the old version afterwards.

```
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> npm uninstall @angular/cli -g

removed 228 packages in 5s
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> ng version
Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 16.2.9
Node: 20.9.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.9 (cli-only)
@angular/cdk                    11.0.1
@angular/cli                    16.2.9 (cli-only)
@angular/fire                   6.1.4
@angular/material               11.2.12
@schematics/angular             16.2.9 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
zone.js                         0.11.4

Warning: The current version of Node (20.9.0) is not supported by Angular.
```

Then I tried without the global param, but for some reason it tries to resolve dependencies during the uninstall, which I don't understand why.

```
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@11.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"11.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"6.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   12 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\xianx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T21_07_34_444Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\xianx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T21_07_34_444Z-debug-0.log
```

The logfile just shows the same errors:

```
'Log files:
C:\Users\xianx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T21_07_34_444Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
Found: @angular/common@11.0.3
node_modules/@angular/common
  peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@11.0.1
  node_modules/@angular/cdk
    @angular/cdk@"11.0.1" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.4
  node_modules/@angular/fire
    @angular/fire@"6.1.4" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"11.0.3" from @angular/forms@11.0.3
  node_modules/@angular/forms
    peer @angular/forms@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.12
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"^11.2.12" from the root project
    @angular/forms@"11.0.3" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.12
  node_modules/@angular/material
    @angular/material@"^11.2.12" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-browser@11.0.3
  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.4
    node_modules/@angular/fire
      @angular/fire@"6.1.4" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.0.3" from @angular/forms@11.0.3
    node_modules/@angular/forms
      peer @angular/forms@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.12
      node_modules/@angular/material
        @angular/material@"^11.2.12" from the root project
      @angular/forms@"11.0.3" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.0.3
    node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
      peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.4
      node_modules/@angular/fire
        @angular/fire@"6.1.4" from the root project
      peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-server@11.0.3
      node_modules/@angular/platform-server
        @angular/platform-server@"11.0.3" from the root project
      @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"11.0.3" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-server@11.0.3
    node_modules/@angular/platform-server
      @angular/platform-server@"11.0.3" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.0.3" from @angular/router@11.0.3
    node_modules/@angular/router
      @angular/router@"11.0.3" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"^11.0.0" from ngx-markdown@11.1.2
    node_modules/ngx-markdown
      ngx-markdown@"^11.1.2" from the root project
    @angular/platform-browser@"11.0.3" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.0.3
  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
    peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.4
    node_modules/@angular/fire
      @angular/fire@"6.1.4" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-server@11.0.3
    node_modules/@angular/platform-server
      @angular/platform-server@"11.0.3" from the root project
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"11.0.3" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"11.0.3" from @angular/platform-server@11.0.3
  node_modules/@angular/platform-server
    @angular/platform-server@"11.0.3" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"11.0.3" from @angular/router@11.0.3
  node_modules/@angular/router
    @angular/router@"11.0.3" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@">=10.0.0" from @ngx-translate/http-loader@6.0.0
  node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader
    @ngx-translate/http-loader@"6.0.0" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@">=10.0.0" from ng-click-outside@7.0.1
  node_modules/ng-click-outside
    ng-click-outside@"7.0.1" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@">=10.0.0" from ngx-json-viewer@3.0.2
  node_modules/ngx-json-viewer
    ngx-json-viewer@"^3.0.2" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from ngx-markdown@11.1.2
  node_modules/ngx-markdown
    ngx-markdown@"^11.1.2" from the root project
  peer @angular/common@">=9.0.0" from ngx-perfect-scrollbar@10.0.1
  node_modules/ngx-perfect-scrollbar
    ngx-perfect-scrollbar@"10.0.1" from the root project
  @angular/common@"11.0.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
node_modules/@agm/core
  @agm/core@"1.1.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
node_modules/@angular/common
  peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
  node_modules/@agm/core
    @agm/core@"1.1.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: I will guess you have just upgraded your NodeJs... Many dependency libraries will not be ompatible with the latest nodeJs when you are not on the latest Angular version. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68159069/4604645) a similar dependencies issue a While ago. The trick is to pace the angular and NodeJs versions when doing an upgrade of a few versions.