# How do you read npm audit ERESOLVE error?

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, npm

I often receive error ERESOLVE similar to below. How do you read it?

```
>npm audit fix
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.1.1" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"12.1.0" from the root project
```

And how do you read it - Which package depends on which? Which end of the tree I have control of? Top or bottom?

Did I add @angular-devkit/build-angular into my app and it needs but cant find angular/compiler ? or is it the other way around?

Comment: It seems you are meeting the dependency conflict (incorrect and potentially broken dependency) issue, try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`, such as: `npm audit fix --force`. If it doesn't take effect, the temporary solution is using prior versions of the node (Downgrading node version) as it causes to happen such this kind of errors sometimes. Reference: [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages).

Comment: its not what i need really. I edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can be wrong but this is what I read:

> Which package depends on which?

Your app directly depends on:

- `@angular/compiler@"12.1.0"`
- `@angular/compiler-cli@"^12.1.0"`
- `@angular-devkit/build-angular@"12.1.0"`

Your app transitively depends on:

- `@angular/compiler@"12.1.1"` from `@angular/compiler-cli@12.1.1` <- which is the actual `@angular/compiler-cli` version installed in your node_modules.
- `@angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next"` from `@angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.0` <- which is the actual `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version installed in your node_modules.

So what I read is that there is a conflict because your app directly depends on `@angular/compiler@"12.1.0"` and transitively on `@angular/compiler@"12.1.1"` (from `@angular/compiler-cli@12.1.1`)
You can probably fix this by adding what it looks like a missing caret, ie `@angular/compiler@"^12.1.0"`.

Unrelated ^, I had a similar problem but all versions where compatible. I deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and installed them again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with following commands:

1. rm package-lock.json
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. yarn install
4. npm i