# using typescript and electron

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

getting error while installing npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree.
used npm install --legacy-peer-deps and npm install --save, but issue not solved
any idea how yo solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)