# Error while executing 'npm install' in aspnet boilerplate react template

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, npm-install, aspnetboilerplate

[![**NPM ERROR**][1]][1]

I have downloaded aspnet boilerplate react template, backend for Dotnet core works fine but react application didn't. Whenever I execute npm install it through the same error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrR3w.png

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency conflict (incorrect and possibly broken dependency), so try using `--force`, or run the command `--legacy-peer-deps`.

If it does not take effect, the temporary solution is to use the previous version of Node.js (downgrade Node.js version), because this error sometimes occurs.

You can read this post, which may help you:

[Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)