# getting "dependency tree error" when running npm install on VScode for Mac

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-install

When  I  try to use  " npm install", I get below errors, I have read all the possible articles but  none of them resolved my issue, I deleted also package-lock.json and also removed node-modules but  none of  them helped. also used "npm cache verify" before "npm i" but didn't  help.
I also  used:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

But it was not helpful.

Any advise is   highly  appreciated.

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: your-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   workbox-webpack-plugin@"4.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   workbox-webpack-plugin@"4.3.1" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^3.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-scripts@">=2.1.3" from react-app-rewired@2.1.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-app-rewired
npm ERR!       peer react-app-rewired@"*" from react-app-rewire-workbox@2.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-app-rewire-workbox
npm ERR!         react-app-rewire-workbox@"^2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer workbox-webpack-plugin@"^3.0.0" from react-app-rewire-workbox@2.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-app-rewire-workbox
npm ERR!   react-app-rewire-workbox@"^2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/afshinshahpari/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/afshinshahpari/.npm/_logs/2021-11-25T16_07_16_430Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hey have you tried `npm install --force`?

Comment: @NanduDharmapalan  Yes but did not  work too

Comment: Okay. Please check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615583/7402956, maybe it will help