# How do you fix -> Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, npm-audit

I'm not familiar with resolving dependency issues. I saw some vulnerabilities after running "npm install" so I ran "npm audit fix" as recommended. I get this error

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: code-split@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: babel-eslint@10.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/babel-eslint
npm ERR!   babel-eslint@"10.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer babel-eslint@"9.x" from eslint-config-react-app@3.0.8
```

It seems to me like I have babel-eslint@10.1.0 but eslint-config-react-app@3.0.8 needs babel-eslint@9.x but I'm not totally sure how to solve this. Should I update eslint-config-react-app@3.0.8?

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "code-split",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "jest": "jest",
    "eslint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^2.7.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "3.0.8",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "json2xml": "^0.1.3",
    "jsonxml": "^1.0.0",
    "md5-file": "^4.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "object-hash": "^2.0.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.2",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.1.3",
    "react-csv": "1.1.1",
    "react-dates": "20.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-draggable": "4.2.0",
    "react-driftjs": "1.1.6",
    "react-ga": "2.5.6",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "2.1.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.18.2",
    "react-image": "4.0.3",
    "react-intl": "2.7.0",
    "react-joyride": "2.2.1",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
    "react-select": "^2.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-stepper-horizontal": "1.0.11",
    "react-string-replace": "0.4.1",
    "react-tracking": "5.6.0",
    "react-youtube": "^7.11.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "swiper": "^4.5.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "universal-cookie": "3.0.4",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.8",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.1.0",
    "jest-cli": "^24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "react-testing-library": "^6.1.2",
    "sinon": "^7.5.0",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
  },
```

Please help me fix this!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages