# React-map-gl-draw unable to install

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am trying to add react-map-gl-draw to my application on top of react-map-gl; however, the error I get is the following:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-map-gl@6.1.18
npm ERR! node_modules/react-map-gl
npm ERR!   react-map-gl@"^6.1.18" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-map-gl@"^5.x" from react-map-gl-draw@1.0.2-alpha.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-map-gl-draw
npm ERR!   react-map-gl-draw@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I haven't been able to find anyone suffering from the same problem. I would appreciate it if anyone could lend me a hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages) helped me. Namely, the flag (--legacy-peer-deps) for installing packages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33001257)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--force` command like this:

```
npm install react-map-gl-draw --force
```