# npm not installing unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Actually, I have a working project in angular but right now I am just trying to revamp the project So I install the npm on this project using `npm install` command but I got the bellow error. Please check the screenshot

[image]

Please help me to reach out this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: Yes, it's working. May I know the exact issue?

Comment: It's a version issue... https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps Check here for further.

Comment: Make it green if you are satisfied with the answer. It would help others.

Comment: Yes, I forget to do this. Now done

Answer (score 2):

By reading the errors, it seems like the `selected-country@^5.0.1` needs `@angular/cdk@~12.x`, but you only have `@angular/cdk@^10.2.3`

You might want to try this:

```
npm update @angular/cdk@12
```

This basically will try to update your `angular/cdk` to version 12.

If this doesn't work. You can also try downgrading your Node.js to a lower version. I had to also downgrade my Node.js when I updated my entire Angular project from version 12 to 13.

If this still doesn't work, you can try out these methods answered by our community.

[Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)