# Unhandled exception occurred running ng serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it. I just got a new machine and before I pulled down my repo, I installed the latest node, Angular Cli, npm and any other package/framework needed by my app. I cloned the repo and updated all local packages in my project to current versions using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates). I then installed the updated packages with >npm install -force to resolve a couple of peer dependency issues. I'll post a screen shoot at the very bottom. But now ng serve doesn't run see error below. Not sure why?

> ➜  client git:(master) ✗ ng serve
> ⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Dev-server address info is not defined.
> See "/private/var/folders/l6/zz0rl4793838rf924b4y0tqc0000gn/T/ng-5kND02/angular-errors.log" for further details.
> ➜  client git:(master) ✗

The error in the index.js file is from this below.

```js
const devServer = createWebpackDevServer(webpackCompiler, devServerConfig);
devServer.startCallback(() => {
  var _a;
  const address = (_a = devServer.server) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.address();
  if (!address) {
    obs.error(new Error(`Dev-server address info is not defined.`));
    return;
  }
  result = {
    success: true,
    port: typeof address === 'string' ? 0 : address.port,
    family: typeof address === 'string' ? '' : address.family,
    address: typeof address === 'string' ? address : address.address,
  };
});
```

>npm install -force

```html
➜  client git:(master) ✗ npm install -f
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm WARN Found: tslib@2.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/tslib
npm WARN   tslib@"^2.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN   22 more (@angular-devkit/build-angular, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm WARN node_modules/ngx-gallery-9
npm WARN   ngx-gallery-9@"^1.0.6" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: tslib@1.14.1
npm WARN node_modules/tslib
npm WARN   peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/ngx-gallery-9
npm WARN     ngx-gallery-9@"^1.0.6" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

added 1163 packages, and audited 1164 packages in 37s

118 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

> I then installed the updated packages with `npm install -force` to resolve a couple of peer dependency issues.

Did you actually manually resolve all the issues or think that the command above would do it for you?

My guess is that the dependencies are not installed properly, but I can be wrong.

You might want to try the solution I just posted [npm not installing unable to resolve dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71535306/npm-not-installing-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree/71535471#71535471). I also included the link in the post for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the old version of the node.
Kindly update your node version to the latest then run the following command.

> sudo n lts

Then run the following command.

```
ng run serve
```

This might help you