# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

When i want to install `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript`.I get an error in terminal

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3 || ^17" from react-redux@7.2.6
```

Comment: Evidently react-redux doesn't yet support React 18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Use "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
because your Application route version is old and you installed new version of Angular CLI dependencies ,so it make conflict between them.