# How do I create a stacked horizontal bar chart with Chart.js in React?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm really struggling to find a clear answer to this question - especially in React.  I'd like to create a stacked horizontal bar chart component for my React application.  This is the type of chart I'm trying to create: https://codepen.io/pen.  The code pasted below is what I've tried to use so far but it isn't rendering currently.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

export default class LineChart extends Component {
  chartRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const ctx = this.chartRef.current.getContext('2d');

    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [
          'Sunday',
          'Monday',
          'Tuesday',
          'Wednesday',
          'Thursday',
          'Friday',
          'Saturday',
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              stacked: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      },

      datasets: [
        {
          data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
          label: 'Total',
          borderColor: '#3e95cd',
          backgroundColor: '#7bb6dd',
          // fill: False,
        },
        {
          data: [70, 90, 44, 60, 83, 90, 100],
          label: 'Accepted',
          borderColor: '#3cba9f',
          backgroundColor: '#71d1bd',
          // fill: False,
        },
        {
          data: [10, 21, 60, 44, 17, 21, 17],
          label: 'Pending',
          borderColor: '#ffa500',
          backgroundColor: '#ffc04d',
          // fill: False,
        },
        {
          data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 0, 16],
          label: 'Rejected',
          borderColor: '#c45850',
          backgroundColor: '#d78f89',
          // fill: False,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas id="myChart" ref={this.chartRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem I would highly recommend this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXuElLhCK8s) video to get the basic framework you need to use ChartsJS with React and then using the official documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to modify it and create more bespoke charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using V2 syntax of Chart.js while using V3. V3 has major breaking changis inclusing all scales are their own object. For all changes please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html).

When using objects for scales you get what you want:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this for me.  The V2 vs V3 explains why I've seen such a confusing mix of solutions.  Can I ask, how would your example look as a React component? I've also tried installing the package using the "npm install react-chartjs-3 chart.js --save" but I'm getting an error that says: "npm ERR! code ERESOLVE" and "npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree".  Do you know why this is?

Comment: according to this stack issue a dependancy conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages