# i cant install vue-router by npm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

i want to install vue-router but some errors occurs

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: routing01@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^2.5.11" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.0.15
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-router
npm ERR!   vue-router@"4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Peyman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-31T07_48_48_170Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Related: [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 14):

The problem is you have incompatible versions of `vue` and `vue-router`.

- `vue@2` requires `vue-router@3`
- `vue@3` requires `vue-router@4`

The error message indicates you have `vue@2.6.14`, and you're trying to install `vue-router@4.0.15`. Note that `npm install -S vue-router` (without a version specifier) defaults to the `latest` version, which is [currently `4.0.15`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router?activeTab=versions).

Don't use the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` npm flags that are suggested in the error message because that would only install incompatible packages that would result in a runtime error.

#### Solution

A quick fix is to install `vue-router@3`:

```bash
npm install -S vue-router@3
```

Or you can upgrade to Vue 3, which requires uninstalling `vue-template-compiler` (the template compiler for Vue 2) and installing `@vue/compiler-sfc` (the template compiler for Vue 3):

```bash
npm uninstall -S vue-template-compiler
npm install -S vue@3 @vue/compiler-sfc
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add by using plugin also using vue-cli.

try `vue add router`

btw use can install vuetify and eslint and many more things using `vue add vuetify` and `vue add eslint`
you can refer this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#plugins

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

This command will tell npm to ignore peer dependencies