# React Rich text editor is not installing

Tags: reactjs, editor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to use React mui rte from [Here](https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte) but when I tried `npm install mui-rte --save` its showing the below error:

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: hiretripple@0.1.0        
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @mui/icons-material@"^5.0.0" from mui-rte@2.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/mui-rte
npm ERR!       mui-rte@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/material@5.8.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     @mui/material@"^5.8.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from mui-rte@2.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/mui-rte
npm ERR!       mui-rte@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!   3 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.8.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   peer @mui/styles@"^5.0.0" from mui-rte@2.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/mui-rte
npm ERR!     mui-rte@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

How can I resolve the problem? or is there any other best text editor that I can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615583/6482248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install this package using

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Then try to install your package