# Error (code ERESOLVE) when in trying to run the command "npm install" on console log

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

I'm on a college project where I got a project with angular and typescript, languages which I have difficulty and I'm having problems when trying to run the project

Why when in trying to run the command install

```
npm install
```

The console return to me:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: sisgeo@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.8.29
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"^0.8.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.9.1" from @angular/core@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^8.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"8.2.14" from @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^8.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\desou\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\desou\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-13T01_56_25_713Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this resource (the problem mainly deals with dependency conflicts):

[Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)