# After removing node_modules folder and later running npm isntall throws error

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

For a fresh installation, I have removed the node_modules folder using the command `rm -rf node_modules/`.Then from the terminal I have run `npm install` in Ubuntu, but now i am getting below error, could someone please advise on what steps should I follow to fix this issue ?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@11.4.0
npm ERR! Found: esbuild@0.15.10
npm ERR! node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR!   dev esbuild@"^0.15.10" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer esbuild@"*" from @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor@2.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor
npm ERR!     dev @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor@"^2.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional esbuild@"^0.14.23" from @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@11.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
npm ERR!   @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@"^11.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: esbuild@0.14.54
npm ERR! node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR!   peerOptional esbuild@"^0.14.23" from @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@11.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
npm ERR!     @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@"^11.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/den/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/den/.npm/_logs/2022-10-15T03_40_29_742Z-debug-0.log
```

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "booktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://someurl.com"
  },
  "author": "BookTest",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "remove-files": "node removeFiles.js",
    "cucumber-report": "node createreport.js",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:simpro-run": "cypress run && npm run cucumber-report",
    "cy:rest-api": "cypress run --headless --spec tests/cypress/integration/restapi/**/*.spec.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.3.0",
    "cypress": "^10.10.0",
    "cypress-dotenv": "^1.2.2",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^4.1.1",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.4.1",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.10",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-fs-cache": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-iconfont": "^10.0.3",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-order": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.4.1",
    "gulp-wait": "0.0.2",
    "lazypipe": "^1.0.2",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions",
    "last 2 Firefox versions",
    "last 2 Safari versions",
    "last 2 Edge versions",
    "IE 11",
    "last 2 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 2 iOS versions",
    "last 2 Samsung versions",
    "last 2 FirefoxAndroid versions"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.4.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.14.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.14.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "idb": "^6.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.6.347"
  }
}
```

Comment: Delete your package-lock.json and do npm install.

Comment: Delete package-lock.json and clean the cache using this `npm cache clean --force`, then try

Comment: @MohamedSameer No i dont have package-lock.json

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I have run the `npm cache clean --force ` which echo `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled`. Then I did npm install, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Try following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Comment: Are you locked in to any versions for any reason, or are you able to change versions to resolve conflicting peer dependencies?

Comment: I had package-lock.json  and i have removed that and tried ```npm install --force```

Comment: I was asking if you must keep to any of the versions shown above in the error message, because it looks like an issue of version clashing. If you can provide a look at package.json that would help immensely.

Comment: @TesterDick I have added my packag.json details to the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like a mis-match of versions, although I couldn't reproduce the same error message.

If you download the `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` repository file, unzip it and copy the example folder that most closely matches your current setup - looks like `/esbuild-cjs` is the closest.

If you use that folder as the project root (rename it whatever you want) and `npm install` to set up node-modules, then look in the node-module folder you will see these versions have been installed.

```js
"cypress": "10.10.0",
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "@13.0.2",
"@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "@2.1.5"
"esbuild": '0.14.54',
```

which is fairly close to the recommendation in the error message.

The `package.json` just has

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "latest",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "latest",
    "cypress": "latest"
  }
}
```

If you want you can change `latest` to the specific versions, and add the other packages you need,

**but don't add the entry for esbuild** because it's correct version is already being installed by `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Any additions you make to `dependencies` or `devDependencies`, you will need to run `npm install` to update `node-modules`.