# Unable to perform npm run build on my functions directory after upgrading firebase-functions and firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have been developing this app for quite a long time yet, and after reading the console warning about an outdated version of `firebase-functions` and that I should upgrade to latest version I finally made the decision to update. Now, even though everything seems to be working properly, I am unable to run `npm run build` successfully when testing on the emulator, since I get a lot of error messages related to a package inside my `node_modules` folder.

I am running the local emulator where all the new code is tested before being deployed into production. And this is what these two packages looked like on my `package.json` file looked before and after updating:

*Before*

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.22.0",
```

*After*

```
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^4.0.0",
```

### The problem

After updating, I am unable to successfully run `npm run build`, and I get a bunch of error related with packages that are inside `node_modules`. Some of this packages are:

```
node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common
```

And the errors are not that verbose and go something like this:

```
21 export declare type Extract<Part extends string> = Part extends `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
```

I'll be attaching a screenshot with some of the errors I'm getting.

### What have I Already tried doing

- **Installed latest version of `firebase-functions`**: Updated only `firebase-functions` with `npm install --save firebase-functions@latest` inside my `functions` directory.

  - This resulted on a dependency conflict with `functions` and `firebase-admin` package as [discussed on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64573177/8840456)
- **Installed latest version of `firebase-admin`**: Solved the dependency issue by running `npm install --save firebase-admin@latest` and by installing latest version of `firebase-functions`.

  - This solved the conflict but this is where the issues started appearing after running `npm run build`
  - I also got a bunch of new errors that resulted from the upgrade, but I solved them and everything seems to be working OK.
- **Removed `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`**: In order to properly re-install dependencies, erased these two files and run `npm install`, but the problem persisted.
- **Upgraded to specific versions of functions and admin**: While diving deeply on this rabbit hole, I noticed that perhaps [upgrading to a specific version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/942#issuecomment-897567834) could help. So I went with `firebase-admin@10.0.0` and `firebase-functions@4.0.0`. But nothing.

### So, What am I looking for?

My workflow is as follows:

- Write new code
- Run `npm run build` to see if everything is ok and the app passes the linter test at a quick glance
- Test code
- Push Code
- ...
- `npm run lint` before deploy (which passes)
- Deploy

So, for me `npm run build` tells me that everything is OK and I can move forward with code. I don't really know if this is necessary or not, but I've been working like this forever. It gives me a safe feeling.

So I want to know why can't I run `npm run build`, what is causing all these errors that I have nothing to do with, and how can I solve this issue.

I am also afraid that this will impact on the deploy of functions, preventing me from deploying correctly since `npm run build` is not passing.

### My Project settings

- **firebase-functions:** 3.20.1
- **firebase-tools:** 11.16.1
- **firebase-admin:** 10.1.0
- **Language**: Typescript
- **Node Version**: 14.21.1 (using with nvm)

### The screenshot

[image: Errors shown on console after running npm run build]

Comment: How about `firebase-admin : v11.2.1` and `firebase-functions : v4.0.2`? Are you facing same error with latest versions also?

Comment: @RoopaM yes! I didn't mention in the question that in-between trials among different versions I also tried with the latest version of `firebase-admin` and It Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely due to an outdated version of Typescript. **Try upgrading typescript to newer version.**

[Update theses packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM9eH.png)