# npm error whenever I try to install a package

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I recently updated some npm packages and now it throws an error whenever I try to install a package with npm. I am new to npm and JS packages.
Attatched is a image of the error.
[image: here is a image of the error message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove your node_modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`)
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can run `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps` and see if it may resolve your problem.

If not you can remove your `node-modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` file and run a fresh `npm install` command.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

**npm config set legacy-peer-deps true** use this  in my case it worked