# I'm new to react and node .Can anyone explain what does" Found: react@16.13.1 node_modules/react" mean?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ethereum, blockchain, node-modules

I am trying to run a project on my local machine but unable to do it in anyway.I have cloned it from Github onto my local machine .This project is bootstrapped with react app and I am new to it .

Here is a link of the repository-
https://github.com/sherwyn11/Pharma-Chain.

As mentioned in the readmd file I followed all intructions.But on doing -npm update I am getting an error.
The error is as follows -

```
  code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: blockchain@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0" from material-ui@0.15.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/material-ui
    npm ERR!   material-ui@"0.15.0" from the root project
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
npm install —-force
```

And then start your project.

Comment: Hossein should i install or update it?

Comment: Check your project dependencies for update with “npm outdated” then update them if new version exist ,if not just install packages with “npm install —force”