# node_modules vanishes and doesn't install any dependency for react app and throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation, npm-install, react-app-rewired

I am trying to install a react app but am unable and it always gives the below error and the whole node_modules folder vanishes.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   @craco/craco@"^6.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/xoxo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xoxo/.npm/_logs/2023-01-24T15_48_03_164Z-debug-0.log
```

And it is not also letting me install `react-app-rewired`

I tried with --force and --legacy-peer-deps but no luck, I am stuck at this since 3 hours, not able to reslove it from anywhere. Also tried methods told for clearing cache and installing again, but no luck their either.

Also for some private packages had used `npm auth` with `$NPM_TOKEN` but still gave the below error:

```
npm auth
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Manage package owners
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm owner add <user> <package-spec>
npm ERR! npm owner rm <user> <package-spec>
npm ERR! npm owner ls <package-spec>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--registry <registry>] [--otp <otp>]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! alias: author
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help owner" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xoxo/.npm/_logs/2023-01-26T07_54_36_914Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Comment: @Sardar I have tried the methods mentioned in the link, but no luck there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the above with:

1. deleting and again cloning the project
2. created npmjs token required for custom private packages, updated .envrc with it.
3. so `npm i` still failed hence used `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` after `npm cache clean --force`

Voila! all dependencies got installed

The mistake I was first doing was trying npm auth, which is not required as `npm` fetches it from the `.envrc` and the `.npmrc` file

Hence, try using these steps if you find any difficulty similar to this