# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree in vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, installation, material-ui

I tried many ways to resolve this from cleaning cache to installing dependancies, like:-

npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux --legacy-peer-deps
npm cache clean --force
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps

Then I tried to set legacy peer deps true using :- npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
And then I installed legacy peer deps and tried again.
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
After this I installed packages like :-
npm i @material-ui/core
npm i @material-ui/icons
and it worked.....

It might show some vulnerabilities but it would run fine.

I was trying to install material ui core and icon package but couldn't complete it because of issue with dependency tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score -1):

You can try different ways it may work but instead of installing packages again and again

1. Set legacy peer deps as true :- npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
2. Then install legacy peer deps :- npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps[using this]
3. Then try installing your packages

Answer (score -1):

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm cache clean --force
```

If it is not working then delete your node modules file and again install it. Also check your node and npm version

Comment: it might be package-versions that need to be installed based on your package.json file.

It gives errors in the npm 7 version and cannot install Node.js modules.

If you will downgrade npm version to 6, those problems will become warnings and the problem will be resolved.