# "ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree" when running npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

Trying to run npm install command for my angular app, but I keep getting dependency errors. I'm new to TypeScript and Angular, what are some ways I should proceed?

I've tried clearing my npm cache and removing node modules and installing them again. However, I'm still getting this error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-dashboard-page@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~5.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <5.0" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~15.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~15.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-debug-0.log
```

Debug log:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.6.4
2 info using node@v18.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\operator-interface-main\client\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ASUS\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 10ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm install
21 verbose argv "install"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 25ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 6 files
34 timing idealTree:init Completed in 20ms
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly fetch manifest @angular/animations@~15.2.6
38 silly logfile done cleaning log files
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations 603ms (cache revalidated)
40 silly fetch manifest @angular/core@~15.2.6
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 109ms (cache revalidated)
42 silly fetch manifest rxjs@~7.8.0
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 366ms (cache revalidated)
44 silly fetch manifest zone.js@~0.13.0
45 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js 107ms (cache revalidated)
46 silly fetch manifest @angular/cdk@^15.2.6
47 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcdk 84ms (cache revalidated)
48 silly fetch manifest @angular/common@~15.2.6
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon 76ms (cache revalidated)
50 silly fetch manifest @angular/compiler@~15.2.6
51 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler 77ms (cache revalidated)
52 silly fetch manifest @angular/forms@~15.2.6
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 90ms (cache revalidated)
54 silly fetch manifest @angular/platform-browser@~15.2.6
55 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 1180ms (cache revalidated)
56 silly fetch manifest @angular/material@^15.2.6
57 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fmaterial 290ms (cache revalidated)
58 silly fetch manifest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~15.2.6
59 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 238ms (cache revalidated)
60 silly fetch manifest @angular/router@~15.2.6
61 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter 203ms (cache revalidated)
62 silly fetch manifest @coreui/angular@^4.4.1
63 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@coreui%2fangular 2032ms (cache revalidated)
64 silly fetch manifest @googlemaps/js-api-loader@^1.15.1
65 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@googlemaps%2fjs-api-loader 399ms (cache revalidated)
66 silly fetch manifest @types/gsap@^3.0.0
67 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fgsap 1648ms (cache revalidated)
68 silly fetch manifest @types/socket.io@^3.0.2
69 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fsocket.io 2418ms (cache revalidated)
70 silly fetch manifest ably@^1.2.4
71 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ably 1953ms (cache updated)
72 silly fetch manifest gsap@^3.11.5
73 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gsap 1501ms (cache updated)
74 silly fetch manifest kioskboard@^2.3.0
75 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/kioskboard 1259ms (cache revalidated)
76 silly fetch manifest tslib@^2.5.0
77 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib 258ms (cache revalidated)
78 silly fetch manifest webrtc-adapter@^8.2.2
79 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webrtc-adapter 701ms (cache updated)
80 silly fetch manifest @angular-devkit/build-angular@~15.2.5
81 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular 3904ms (cache updated)
82 silly fetch manifest @angular/compiler-cli@~15.2.6
83 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 2051ms (cache updated)
84 silly fetch manifest typescript@~5.0.4
85 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 4762ms (cache updated)
86 silly fetch manifest typescript@>=4.8.2 <5.0
87 timing idealTree Completed in 26540ms
88 timing command:install Completed in 26547ms
89 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
89 verbose stack     at [failPeerConflict] (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1381:25)
89 verbose stack     at [loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1347:34)
89 verbose stack     at async [loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1326:23)
89 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:929:11)
89 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:207:7)
89 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
89 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
89 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:146:5)
89 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:89:5)
90 verbose cwd C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\operator-interface-main\client
91 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
92 verbose node v18.15.0
93 verbose npm  v9.6.4
94 error code ERESOLVE
95 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
96 error
97 error While resolving: [1mangular-dashboard-page[22m@[1m0.0.0[22m
97 error Found: [1mtypescript[22m@[1m5.0.4[22m[2m[22m
97 error [2mnode_modules/typescript[22m
97 error   [33mdev[39m [1mtypescript[22m@"[1m~5.0.4[22m" from the root project
97 error
97 error Could not resolve dependency:
97 error [35mpeer[39m [1mtypescript[22m@"[1m>=4.8.2 <5.0[22m" from [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@[1m15.2.6[22m[2m[22m
97 error [2mnode_modules/@angular/compiler-cli[22m
97 error   [33mdev[39m [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@"[1m~15.2.6[22m" from the root project
97 error   [35mpeer[39m [1m@angular/compiler-cli[22m@"[1m^15.0.0[22m" from [1m@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m@[1m15.2.5[22m[2m[22m
97 error   [2mnode_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m
97 error     [33mdev[39m [1m@angular-devkit/build-angular[22m@"[1m~15.2.5[22m" from the root project
97 error
97 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
97 error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
97 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
98 error
98 error
98 error For a full report see:
98 error C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-eresolve-report.txt
99 verbose exit 1
100 timing npm Completed in 26613ms
101 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1681211508389
102 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1681211508392
103 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1681211508413
104 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1681211508414
105 verbose code 1
106 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T11_11_48_335Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I overcome this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you tried tracking down and understanding the error? You have `typescript` version `~5.0.4` in your `devDependencies`, however Angular is not compatible with this version of TypeScript yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 3):

What this is saying is that the typescript version is not compatible with the angular version you are using.

Try to delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file if those exist.

Then you can run `npm i typescript@5.0 --save` wich is the version that it is saying angular `@angular/compiler-cli@15.2.6` dependency use.

Comment: Oh you said it first.

Answer (score 0):

The @angular/compiler-cli package requires a version of TypeScript between 4.8.2 and 5.0, while your project has TypeScript 5.0.4 installed.

just downgrade it to version 5.0 that should work for you.

```
npm install typescript@5.0
```

Comment: If this works please mark ALourenco answer as the correct one and not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency you're trying to add requires you're TS version to be <5, run `npm i typescript@~4` then try installing your package again.

Answer (score -2):

```
npm audit --fix
```

Enabling force flag would help you disabling the error and installs the deps

```
npm i -f
```

(optional) maybe need to update the deps but this could be a breaking change

```
npm outdated --latest
```

Comment: The first and last solution won't change anything about the error. It's a totally valid peer dependency conflict. The second solution `npm i -f` will simply ignore the error and will cause follow-up issues when building the application.