# How do I read NPM dependency-conflict errors?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, dependencies

I'm trying to run `npm install` on a fairly outdated project and keep running into NPM dependency errors. I've ran into hundreds of errors like these before in various projects, but I have yet to find a good guide on how to read them. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages) comes closest but does not really describe a general case, and [these docs](https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html) help me understand the underlying structures of my dependencies, but do not really help me debug.

Below is the error I'm running into right now, starting at the bottom, my interpretation is that `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26` requires `react-dom@">=16.7.0"`, but beyond that I don't follow. It looks like `react-dom@18.2.0` requires `react@"^18.2.0"`, but I don't see how this is relevant given that `react-dom` isn't even a dependency in my project (at least not one explicitly stated).

I think that the indentation block means that the error comes from a nested dependency, but I really don't know what to make of this. Similarly, The error above is also related to `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26`, but I can't tell if it causes the error below, or vice versa (or maybe they are unrelated entirely?).

I'm looking to get 1) general advice on how to decipher NPM dependency errors into actionable steps, and 2) recommendations on how to fix this specific error.

Also note I've tried to `npm update @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26` but I run into similar errors.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Also if it helps, the full list of my NPM dependencies is here:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.3.12",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.26",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.16.7",
    "@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas": "^2.3.22",
    "@nozbe/watermelondb": "^0.24.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^4.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^5.1.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.4",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.12",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "generate-username-from-email": "^1.0.2",
    "graphql": "^16.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^3.2.7",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.38",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.5.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-idle-timer": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-keychain": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-vimeo-iframe": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.21.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "unique-username-generator": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific error is caused by a version number mismatch. You are specifying a version of React for your project (`17.0.1`) in your `package.json`, and also (via `@aws-amplify/ui-react@^1.2.26` which requires `react-dom@>=16.7.0` **but** is currently using `react-dom@18.2.0`, which in turn requires `react@18.2.0`) loading an incompatible version as a peer dependency. The reason for this is that at some point a version of react-dom was required that is now too high of a version number, and you should be able to fix this by downgrading the version of `react-dom` to match your version of `react` (17.0.1), which will still satisfy the requirement `react-dom@>=16.7.0`.

In this case, where the already-resolved dependencies have formed a bit of a knot, you might also solve the problem by deleting your `package-lock.json` and rerunning `npm install`.

**How to read NPM dependency errors?**

The good news is, you're on the right lines with your own investigation. You should try getting the dependency graph for your project (`npm list`) and tracing through which modules require which submodules - this can have several layers of nesting. It's also useful to run `npm list [module]` to see what dependencies a given module has. This lets you see at a glance what existing dependencies might be affected when you add a new module. If you run into the same problem again, this might be enough to get you unstuck.

We can also take a closer look at some of the error messages you were getting.

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
```

The key things to note here are that the version of `react-dom` with the dependency is **not** using the same version number as where it's being required. This usually means that there are multiple places where it's a dependency, and NPM has tried to solve all conflicts already, but because NPM lists all places where a conflicting dependency is required, we know that's not the case here. I recommend reading up about the purpose of `package-lock.json` if you want to understand this in more depth.

`@aws-amplify/ui-react` is specified as coming 'from the root project', so we know it's a top-level dependency. Usually with a version mismatch, if you can trace all the dependencies through to the root dependency, you can look at potentially bumping one or more root dependencies to solve the problem that way.

Lastly, you can pin a specific version of a dependency and overwrite NPM's own version resolution mechanism. This is most useful when you want to use a patched version of a nested dependency without updating everything that depends on that package, e.g. to remove a vulnerability in the project. It's risky if you're not sure what you're doing, though. You can do this with the `overrides` section of the `package.json`.

Answer (score 15):

Ok this issue has been bothering me for a *long* time but I finally have a TLDR way to explain it:

### TLDR:

1. Read the least-indented "While/Found/Could not" parts of the error message to understand the conflict in this format: *"While trying to install Z, I Found I had already installed module X version 1.0, but then as a result, I Could not satisfy this other requirement that we use module X version 2.0"*.
2. All the other lines are just answering the question, *"Where did the thing in the line above come from?"*

### In-depth explanation

Let's consider your error message as an example:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

1. Read the "top-level" (least-indented) parts of the error message first to get the high-level understanding of the problem.

   - The message follows this "While/Found/Could not" format: *While trying to install Z, I Found I had already installed module X version 1.0, but then as a result, I Could not satisfy this other requirement that we use X version 2.0"*.

     - In your example, it's: *"While trying to install myapp@0.0.1, I Found I had installed react@17.0.1, but then as a result, I Could not satisfy the requirement of having react@"^18.2.0"*.

       ```
        npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.1
        npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
        (...)
        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
        npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0 resolution.
       ```
2. All the other lines are just answering the question, *"Where did the thing in the line above come from?"*

   1. In your example, when you read the first half of the conflict:

      ```
      npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
      ```

      1. You then ask, "Where did `react@17.0.1` come from?" and look at the next line:

         ```
         npm ERR! node_modules/react
         ```
      2. A: It was found in `node_modules/react`.
      3. Q: Ok, why was it there? *(looks at next line)*

         ```
         npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
         ```
      4. A: Because the root project `package.json` said to install it at that specific version. *(looks at next line)*

         ```
         npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
         ```
      5. A: Also, even if it wasn't required by the root `package.json`, we needed to have `react@">= 16.7.0"` because it was required by another package we had installed: `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26`.
      6. Q: Ok, where did `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26` come from? *(looks at next line)*

         ```
         npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
         ```
      7. A: It was found in `node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react`.
      8. Q: Ok, why was it there? *(looks at next line)*

         ```
         npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
         ```
      9. A: Because the root project `package.json` said to install it.
      10. **Summary of the first half of the conflict:** We had `react@17.0.1` installed because the root `package.json` said to install it, and also we needed to have at least `>= 16.7.0` because that is required by `@aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26"`, which our root `package.json` says to install.
   2. You then look at the second half of the conflict:

      ```
      npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
      npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
      ```

      1. Q: Why were you trying to install `react@"^18.2.0"`?
      2. A: Because it was required by `react-dom@18.2.0` (as you can see at the end of that second line).
      3. Q: Ok, where did `react-dom@18.2.0` come from?

         ```
         npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
         ```
      4. A: It was already installed in `node_modules`.
      5. Q: Ok, why?

         ```
         npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26
         ```
      6. A: It was required by `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26`. It says we need to have a version of `react-dom` `>= 16.7.0`, so I guess it installed the latest version.
      7. Q: Where did `ui-react` come from?

         ```
         npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
         ```
      8. A: It was already installed in `node_modules`.
      9. Q: Why?

         ```
         npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.26" from the root project
         ```
      10. A: The root project (`package.json`) said to install it.
      11. **Summary of the second half of the conflict:** We're trying to install `react@"^18.2.0"` because it's required by `react-dom@18.2.0`, which is in turn the latest version of a package required by `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26`, which is in turn what we specified to install in our root `package.json`.
   3. You can then summarize the conflict: Our root `package.json` says to install `react@17.0.1`, but then it says to install `@aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.26`, which is leading us to try to install `react@"^18.2.0"`.
   4. You can then summarize how to resolve the conflict: We can either:

      1. update our `package.json` to specify to install `react@"^18.2.0"`, or
      2. update our `package.json` to specify a version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react` that works with `react@17.0.1`, or
      3. we can update our `package.json` to change *both* the version of `react` and the version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react` to versions that work together, or
      4. (most-complicated) we can try to find and manually specify in our `package.json` a version of `react-dom` that is `>= 16.7.0` (and thus satisfies the second half of the conflict) but which is still compatible with `react@17.0.1` (the first half of the conflict).