# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving:

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

im using Angualr 15 , and i try to install an npm for extract the HTML to PDF , i try many package and every time it display to me this message :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@15.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.1.5" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@15.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^15.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^15.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"15.2.4" from @angular/localize@15.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)
npm ERR!   2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@15.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"15.2.4" from @angular/localize@15.2.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!       peerOptional @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.6
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)
npm ERR!     2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

How can i solve it ,  and thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it should suggests, you can either:

- force the installation `npm i --force`
- Install all the dependencies `npm i --legacy-peer-dep`

Otherwise, you can

- Delete `package.lock.json`
- Remove your node_modules folder

Comment: still not working

Comment: I have updated with more solutions