# Getting error message while installing 'ngx-toastr' in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am getting the following error message when I try to install 'ngx-toastr'. I am also using Bootstrap to build my website.

ERROR

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=16.0.0-0" from ngx-toastr@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-toastr
npm ERR!   ngx-toastr@"*" from the root project
```

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.11
Node: 16.20.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.4 
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1402.11 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         14.2.11 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   14.2.11 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          14.2.11 (cli-only)
```

Comment: There seems to be no error just info of the package versions

Comment: You are trying to install the latest version of ngx-toastr in your project. ngx-toastr v17 is only compatible with Angular >= 16, see the [docs](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#dependencies). Apparently, you are using an older version of Angular. You need to install an older version of ngx-toastr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: @VinayakSutar error is self explanatory ngx-toaster version 17 is not compatible with angular v14 either upgrade angular version to v16 or downgrade ngx-toaster to make it functional

Answer (score 1):

The error you are encountering indicates that there is a version compatibility issue between ngx-toastr and the version of @angular/common installed in your project.

The version of ngx-toastr you are trying to install (17.0.2) requires @angular/common version >=16.0.0, but your current project has Angular version 14.2.11.

You are trying to install ngx-toastr@17.0.2. Since ngx-toastr version 17 requires Angular version 16 or higher, so install the updated angular version or Look for the version that matches your Angular version or has a peer dependency on @angular/common with a version compatible with your project. For example, if there is a version that requires @angular/common@^14.2.0, you can install it by running:npm install ngx-toastr@^14.2.0

```
npm install ngx-toastr@^14.2.0
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?