# npm install stops at '@react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.17" from the root project'

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, react-navigation-stack

I've been trying to run 'npm install' in my command prompt. The process works for some time, but when it reaches the time for the installation of react-navigation/stack, it just stopped and never continued.

I tried installing the latest version of Nodejs and npm on my computer, but this didn't fix anything. This is what I get in the command prompt:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: first@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-navigation/native@6.1.8
npm WARN node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm WARN   @react-navigation/native@"7.24.0" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.9
npm WARN node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm WARN   @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.5.8" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: first@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-navigation/native@6.1.8
npm WARN node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm WARN   @react-navigation/native@"7.24.0" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@6.3.18
npm WARN node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.17" from the root project
```

When it reaches 'npm WARN   @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.17" from the root project', it just stops there forever.

Comment: Looks like you have problems with the peer dependencies. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615583/9038475) might help. Otherwise you can search for "npm install could not resolve peer dependency".

Comment: It's not actually an error. It's just that when I run npm install, it stops at ''npm WARN @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.17" and doesn't continue to install the other packages. That's the problem I have.

Comment: So, have you tried `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` or `npm install --force`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both npm install --legacy-peer-deps and npm install --force, but none of them worked.