# npm install throwing Could not resolve dependency error

Tags: angular, npm

I'm currently using Angular version 13.

When I try to run `npm install` command, getting the below errors. How to fix these errors?

```
> npm install


npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-responsive-carousel@2.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=6.1.0" from @angular-slider/ngx-slider@2.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-slider/ngx-slider
npm ERR!     @angular-slider/ngx-slider@"^2.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/fire, @angular/flex-layout, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.2.14" from angular-responsive-carousel@2.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-responsive-carousel
npm ERR!   angular-responsive-carousel@"^2.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.2.14" from angular-responsive-carousel@2.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-responsive-carousel
npm ERR!     angular-responsive-carousel@"^2.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: You can't fix them, you're trying to install mutually incompatible dependencies. If you did what the message suggested, which might force an install, they likely still wouldn't actually _work_.

Comment: Yeah, I forced it, but still, the app won't run. any solution for this?

Comment: @boycod3 what about package.json?

Comment: Find mutually compatible dependencies - read what it tells you, e.g. the responsive carousel wants Anguar 11, so either downgrade Angular or find a more up-to-date replacement for the library.

Comment: Does that mean the carousel needs to be updated to 11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: no, not clear about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`