# Conflicting peer dependency while upgrading Angular (8 to 9)

Tags: angular, npm

I am following the Angular Update guide. I pass the following command:

```
cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8" -C
```

But the following issue is raised:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: genxml@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.15" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.15" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@">=9.0.0 < 10" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.15
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.15" from the root project
```

If I understand correctly, @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.15 requires a version of @angular/compiler-cli that is between 9.0.0 and 10. However, the version of @angular/compiler-cli I have listen in my package.json is :

"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13"

What is the issue here?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the NodeModule folder and the package.lock.json file and repeat the update. Also try to add to the command `--legacy-peer-deps`